# Chrome Extension for Stackoverflow - Customize the color scheme

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

I created a google chrome extension that allows you to choose custom themes in order to make pretty the code that you read.

[image]

The extension injects CSS (Lite extension) and saves your preference theme. The idea is to create a group of themes and also customize the code of GitHub and BitBucket.

You can install the extension accesing to this [URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/color-dev/kjccccpbheobmffklpejpgjapcbnlkng)

The code is at GitHub in this direction [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rodrigore/ColorDev)

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Uh-oh. Bug report already: you currently format *block quotes* as code blocks. I don't think that's the expected behavior. It's certainly not what I expected. Still, *great* piece of work. Obviously I'm using it already. :-)

Comment: I made this in order to have an homogeneus theme in the page, but it's a good issue for the future. BTW, now I added more colour schemes, check it out.